# Notify property changed on static class

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I need help with a curious problem. I haven't managed to find anything similar on SO.

I have a static class used for logging in the system and now I have to bind the state of the log on the UI.

Is there a solution to this since implementing INotifyPropertyChanged forces one to use an instance member(which is an event in this case) and the class itself is static.

I would like to avoid retailoring the class to use singleton or any of those workarounds if it can be avoided.

Comment: Change notifications *are* INotifyPropertyChanged. Using a static class in such a scenario doesn't make much sense anyway - INPC is used for *data binding* which isn't useful with static classes. There is no object to bind to. Whom do you want to notify and what do you want to do with that notification?

Comment: I see. Well I want to notify all whom it may concerne :) And I disagree. There is no object to bind to but there is data to bind to and thats why the x:Static keywrd is introdouced. The only thing that I am missing is the other way and that is when somebody changes the state from code. At that point I would like to notify the UI.

Comment: Note that since WPF 4.5. *there is* a mechanism to notify about value changes of a static property. See the linked Q&As.

Comment: Question to all. Is it bad practice to raise an event from a static class to the UI. I have an example that does so

Comment: @Wheels73 Ask the WPF team at Microsoft. They have invented the `public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged` concept for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @Clemens - I'll take that as a yes then! :) Thanks...